# How to fetch taxonomy fields

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am using drupal 7.36. My question is I have created one taxonomy term **"skin type"**.In this **skin type** I have created many fields.So I want to fetch all taxonomy terms.

How can I fetch this using query or any other way ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fetch taxonomy term data have different function to use depend on requirement .

- [Taxonomy_get_children](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_children/7)
- [Taxonomy_get_tree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7)

Custom Code :

```
<?php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->fieldCondition('field_ingredients', 'tid', $term_id_of_pepper)
$result = $query->execute();
if (isset($result['taxonomy_term'])) {
  $tids = array_keys($result['taxonomy_term']);
  $terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', $tids);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have archive this use view too, but in slightly different way compare Ashlar.

1. Add  **Taxonomy term: Term ID**  in CONTEXTUAL FILTERS.
2. Add  **Taxonomy term: Parent term**  in RELATIONSHIPS.  (leave Require this relationship unchecked.)
3. Add **Taxonomy term: Parent term** in filter section. select **great than 0**.
4. do not forget to filter your taxnonmy term in mycase Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name (= Business Directory).
5. add Taxonomy term: Rendered Taxonomy term to your fields , select relationship to **parent**
   , check the Exclude from display.
6. In setting, under FORMAT section. In grouping field 1, select **(Parent) Taxonomy term: Rendered Taxonomy term**.

You should good to go. you can use view tpl to add more class base on the group. I have enclose my screenshot for references. Sorry for my English.

[image]

Comment: I wont to fetch only parents term using custom code not using views.

Answer (score 0):

These functions would help

- [Taxonomy_get_children](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_children/7)
- [Taxonomy_get_tree](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7)

try this too:

```
 $v = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($machine_name);
  $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($v->vid);

  foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $parentree = taxonomy_get_parents_all($res->tid);
        $strarr = array();
        foreach ($parentree as $parent) {
            $parentList[] = $parent->tid;
        }
  }

    $child_term = taxonomy_term_load($parent_tid[0]);
    $parent_term_level1 = taxonomy_term_load($parent_tid[1]);
    $parent_term_level2 = taxonomy_term_load($parent_tid[2]);
```

Comment: HI Using this code I didn't get only parents id but also get the child id. so how can I get the only parents term ?

Comment: I've modified code please try. you have to observe your taxonomy and decide which level will be the parent level or just put some logic to find out largest level and select it as  a parent.